# Changing my width on iframe is cutting them

Tags: html, css, iframe

So i made this iframe graphs:
[Graph's iframe image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WkGgB.png)

and i want to make its width lower without removing part of it

I tried to do:

```
        <style>
            h3{
                font: italic small-caps bold 16px/2 cursive;
                text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px pink;
                margin-top: 1%;
            }
            #iframesS{ /* This is for all the iframes + h3 descriptions to them, i made a container with iframesS id  */
                display: block;
                box-sizing: border-box;
                margin-left: auto;
                margin-right: auto;
            }
            iframe{
                /* Here i tried to play with width %, but it cut the iframe every time */
            }
        </style>
```

Comment: Please include the code of your iframe as well so that others can see how you have implemented it. For more details please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
<div class="iframe-section">
  <iframe src="" width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0"></iframe>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.iframe-section{
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 75%; 
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.iframe-section iframe{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100% !important;
  height: 100% !important;
}
```